# What is the slot order when inserting four RDIMM DRx4 memory sticks into a GIGABYTE MD80-T0 Motherboard?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

tl;dr: I have a GIGABYTE MD80-T0 motherboard and four Kingston KVR21R15D4K4 memory sticks. I would like to get the machine booting past BIOS POST code 0xB7.

I am assembling a server from parts for a small business. This is not my first rodeo, it is my second. As in the second time I've assembled a server from parts. I assume everyone on this site knows more about the intricacies of enterprise hardware than I do. If I've managed to do something incredibly dumb and wasted everyone's time I apologize profusely and my shame is infinite.

Currently the system will boot and hang on status code 0xB7. [Memory install instructions detailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laNU4.png). After a flurry of POST codes, it **SEEMS** to flip to status 0xAF (DXE_EXIT_BOOT_SERVICES) then to 0xB0 (RT_SET_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS_MAP_BEGIN) then back to 0xAF. I never see it flip to 0xB1 (RT_SET_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS_MAP_END), which seems odd. But it may just be that the board cuts out the VGA output in that part of the boot process. I don't know how to know enough about the chips to say. When the VGA out cuts back in, POST code 0xB7 (DXE_CONFIGURATION_RESET) is up with an on screen message of "Please wait for chipset to initialize..." and there it hangs.

The entire reason I've come to believe this has to do with the memory slot order is entirely based off this newegg.com review of the board: newegg.com/Product/SingleProductReview.aspx?ReviewID=4399951.

Relevant bit of the review:

> Cons: 
>   Manual could be better. I found the memory installation instructions
>   lacking. BIOS should have given me a memory configuration error
>   instead of just hanging at "Please wait Initialize chipset".

Slot fill orders I have tried, one attempt per line:

- DIMM_P0_A0,DIMM_P0_B0,DIMM_P1_E0,DIMM_P1_F0
- DIMM_P0_A0,DIMM_P1_E0
- [no slots] (error code 0x53 as expected)
- DIMM_P0_A0,DIMM_P0_A1,DIMM_P0_A2,DIMM_P1_E0 (shame)

motherboard manual: http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/server_manual_md80-tm0_e_v1002.pdf

memory spec sheet: kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR21R15D4K4_64.pdf

(I don't have enough dingleberries to make this a real link yet sorry <3)

Partial parts list:

- GIGABYTE MD80-TM0
- **2x** SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" 500GB MZ-75E500B/AM
- **2x** Intel Xeon E5-2620 V4 2.1 GHz LGA 2011
- **4x** Kingston KVR21R15D4K4
- EVGA SuperNOVA 750 G2 220-G2-0750-XR
- **2x** AYA 8" 4-Pin Molex Male to 8pin EPS-12V Converter Adapter

Comment: Assembling servers from components is  something most professionals on ServerFault oppose (despite any savings you might achieve on initial cost of the hardware, the total cost of ownership is nearly always higher. Nobody pays list prices for brand-servers.) and you're more likely to get useful answers on SuperUser (check if they have more tags!)

Comment: Probably saved me an argument or five. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the slot order had nothing to do with it. The board had v3 of the BIOs, the processors I was using needed v4 of the BIOs. The only way to update the BIOs, it seems, is to have a CPU that will play nice with the current BIOs. Attempting to use the mangement LAN port did not work, the board wouldn't even pull an IP. Unsurprising without a CPU, I know. Gigabyte support was very determined this would work. It did not. I ended up shipping the board to Gigabyte for a BIOs update, then everything was groovy. Hopefully this saves someone some time.

If you happen to have a v3 processor laying around that would also work. Just follow the BIOs update process in the manual.